# Run the query saved in MS Access with required parameters through Pyodbc?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am using Pyodbc to connect my program with MS Access. In the Access database, I pre-created some queries that require parameters. How can I pass values to parameters of the queries when executing them in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Access database contains saved parameter queries they are exposed by Access ODBC as stored procedures and can be invoked using the ODBC `{call ...}` syntax. For example, with a saved query named [ClientEmails] ...

```sql
PARAMETERS prmLastName Text ( 255 );
SELECT Clients.ID, Clients.LastName, Clients.FirstName, Clients.Email
FROM Clients
WHERE (((Clients.LastName)=[prmLastName]));
```

... the following Python code will run that query and return results for a specific Last Name:

```python
cmd = "{call ClientEmails(?)}"
params = ("Thompson",)
crsr.execute(cmd, params)  # pyodbc "cursor" object
for row in crsr.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a generalized example.  First, connect to the database.  Then, issue commands.  The command is just a string.  You can incorporate variables from elsewhere in your code through simple string concatenation.

```
import pyodbc

connStr = """
DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
DBQ=C:\full\path\to\your\PYODBC.accdb;
"""
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

desired_column = "Forename"
table_name = "Student"
command = "SELECT " + desired_column + " FROM " + table_name

cursor.execute(command)
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print(row)
```